How to display Roll up columns output in ADO Dashboard?
I can see the Rollup columns display required information for me in the Backlogs.
But, I want to display Roll up columns data in ADO Dashboard.
Is there any way to achieve this may be, by using Query etc...? Please let me know
I am primarily looking for the below ones

Progress by Story Points
Progress by all work Items
Progress by User Story
Progress by Task

I have tried looking for Widgets but no luck yet
